# Where should a command line tool store cache files in OS X?

Tags: macos, command-line

`/var/cache` is missing, `~/Library/Caches` seems to be for full-fledged applications rather than command line tools, tools I've seen in the wild do horrible things (like use the user's home directory). Where is the correct - or at least predictable and reliable - location?

Comment: you mean like the "open $TMPDIR../C/"

Comment: At the page  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/OpenSource/Conceptual/ShellScripting/PortingScriptstoMacOSX/PortingScriptstoMacOSX.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004268-TP40003517, see the heading File System Hierarchy.

Comment: @Buscar웃SD Are the names "C" and "T" documented? Looks like `getconf DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR` returns the same but is undocumented.

Comment: @DavidVincent That's a wonderful link that originally took me a while to find, but this is one question I still had after reading most of the documents linked there.

Comment: @TristanBerger, I think that C and T are from 10.8 and beyond.  In 10.6, they are -Caches- and -Tmp- (the minus signs are part of the name, not markup).  The DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR and DARWIN_USER_TEMP_DIR are valid through all 10.x I believe.

Comment: @TristanBerger, I should have asked what kind of tool you were making, and what kind of cache it wants.  In the meantime, find a tool that caches stuff but doesn't do horrible things, and see if its approach works.  Maybe look at tools written or ported by Apple. Maybe emacs or vi.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the type of data being cached - is it per user or system wide?

If per user, there's nothing wrong with using a dot-prefixed directory in the user's home directory (that's what it's for, after all, and very much the UNIX way) or perhaps `/tmp/<username>` if the data is not to be persisted. If it's system wide and meant to be persisted, check the `hier` manual page - `/var/db/<appname>` may be an option?

One other Mac OS-specific option is to use `/var/folders` (as documented in `hier(7)`). As mentioned, you can retrieve the user-specific temporary directory by calling `getconf DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR`.